# C++: Unrecognized or Unsupported array type - opencv ARMminipc

Tags: c++, opencv, arm, debian, qt-creator

I want to create simple C++ program to show output from webcam.This is my pro file:

```
QT       += core
QT       -= gui
TARGET = camera
CONFIG   += console
CONFIG   -= app_bundle
PKGCONFIG += opencv
TEMPLATE = app
SOURCES += main.cpp
LIBS += -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui
```

and this is my cpp file

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

VideoCapture cap;
Mat cam;

namedWindow("camera",1);

for(;;)
{
    cap.open(0);
    cap>>cam;
    imshow("camera",cam);

    waitKey(10);
}

    return a.exec();
}
```

and the result is:

> VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument (8x)
>
> libv4l2: error setting pixformat: Device or resource busy
>
> HIGHGUI ERROR: libv4l unable to ioctl S_FMT
>
> libv4l2: error setting pixformat: Device or resource busy
>
> libv4l1: error setting pixformat: Device or resource busy
>
> HIGHGUI ERROR: libv4l unable to ioctl VIDIOCSPICT
>
> OpenCV Error: Bad Flag (parameter or structure field) (unrecognized or unsupported array type) in cvGetMat, file /build/buildd-opencv_2.3.1-11-armhf-d9JIli/opencv-2.3.1/modules/core/src/array.cpp, line 2482
>
> terminate called after throwing and instance of 'cv::Exception'
>
> what(): /build/buildd-opencv_2.3.1-11-armhf-d9JIli/opencv-2.3.1/modules/core/src/array.cpp:line 2482: error: (-206) Unrecognized or unsupported array type in function cvGetMat

When I delete the loop for(;;) in my cpp, the webcam will show image only. not a streaming from webcam.

This code works on Windows, but it didn't work on Linux, or the miniPC. How can I fix my code?

I'm using QtCreator 2.5.0 Qt4.8.2 OpenCV 2.3.1 Debian in ARM miniPC Cubieboard2

Comment: Why have you got `cap.open(0);` *inside* the `for(;;)` loop ?

Comment: yes, please, the open(0) has to go before the loop. and check the return value !

Comment: I already tried to put it outside the loop, but the result is the same. I want the result to be like camera viewfinder or webcam

Comment: My mistake, I hadn't rebuilt it before. After I built with cap.open(0) outside the loop, it works fine. Thanks for your help!